# Combining multiple ImageViews to one

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have many ImageViews, which were created programmatically, and this causes lags in the app, especially when sliding between different tabs.

I think a good solution might be to combine them into a single ImageView, but I'm not sure how I can do that.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You mean create an ImageView and then change the image with different paths?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that (I'm fairly new to android studio)

Comment: What do you want to do, explain it clear please

Comment: This graph:
https://imgur.com/a/MaSyTlu
is comprised of may little segments of ImageViews (a lot of straight lines). I would like for it to be a single imageview.

Comment: You say that every rectangle it's an ImageView?? Wow, then I can not help

Comment: Is there any other way to add lines programmatically?

Comment: I'd look for a library to do the graphs